# JNDI exmple for connecting to a named instance of MsSQL

Tags: sql-server-2005, jndi, kettle, pentaho-data-integration

We're using Pentaho Data Integration(Open source ETL tool) and are trying to use a JNDI connection to connect to a MS SQL 2005 database.  If we use a default instance on the server it worked fine, however issue that we are having is trying to get it to connect to a named instance.

If you could provide an example or somewhere to look we'd be grateful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Because Microsoft recommends that you run named instances on different ports, they decided to completely ignore the named instance when you include the port number.

Therefore you can either drop the port number and append the named instance, e.g. `hostname\instance` or again drop the port number and use the property `instanceName=myinstance`.

Not sure how this translates to JNDI but we have been successful using this in Spoon with the SQL Server JDBC driver and integrated windows security.